# Raspberry Pi / PS Eye - Cannot Load Mixer Controls: Invalid Argument

Tags: alsa

[image]I want to record with a PS Eye (USB Camera-B4.09.24.1) for an DIY Amazon Echo with Raspberry Pi 2b.

When I attempt this in alsamixer, it exits with the following error when I use F6 to change to the PS Eye soundcard:

> cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument

Do any of you know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: You could have a look at `sudo journalctl -xn 15` immediately afterward to see if there are any clues in the system log.  This may be a driver issue (which may or may not leave a trace in the logs); dunno how well playstation cameras are supported.  See gooberings comment WRT the audio here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/65932/5538

Comment: I added a picture of the system log.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm running into the exact same issue. Same error (in red) in the log.

Comment: As indicated in the screenshot, the error is: "raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 3)"